# Problem with LCD keypad shield and Arduino Uno R3

Tags: arduino-uno, power, lcd

I have a problem with powering my LCD Keypad Shield from a DC cable (4 AA batteries or 9V battery). Everything looks good, but the LCD screen doesn't display anything. When I used a USB cable, the screen works as it should.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you please give us more than "it doesn't work?" That's really hard to diagnose. Please edit with circuit diagrams. Thanks!

Comment: OK. First of all, have you tried adjusting the contrast? I don't know why that would change between power sources but it might. [This image](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/images/1/1e/Arduino_Shield8.png) labels the thing you need to turn to adjust the contrast. Turn it slowly from one side to the other until you can see something. Also: the AAs can't provide enough voltage- even when completely full. (They're in series, right?) Add two more in series to achieve 9V at full power. Also, try replacing the 9V if needed since they drain quickly. Also, connecting to VIN and GND *for sure*?

Comment: Sorry. I plug the LCD Keypad Shield to my Arduino Uno R3. I connected Arduino to computer by USB cable and load example cod from this page: http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arduino_LCD_KeyPad_Shield_%28SKU:_DFR0009%29 Everything worked perfectly. When I disconnected Arduino, and instead of USB cable I used DC cable display didn't worked. The power led and LCD backlight was on but there where no letters or any other mark on display. When I changed cable back to USB it worked normal again.

Comment: You originally mentioned a battery, so I was giving advice on a batter. Can you please post a picture of your wiring for the battery to the Arduino? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to change the contrast and to change the power supplier but it dosen't work. With 9V display only blinks from time to time. I'm affraid that something isn't right with my Arduino.

Comment: Do you have a wall adapter that's 9V? I still think the battery might not be full.

Comment: Neither 4xAA nor a typical 9V battery is really suited to powering an Arduino.  Fundamentally, the board is not engineered for battery usage, but if you must, try *at least* 5 Alkaline or 6 rechargeable AA cells (and 7 wouldn't be bad).

Comment: Are you powering the arduino externally with a 9V battery or the LCD with a 9V battery. Most LCDs have lower voltage ratings. Can you be more specific about what kind of DC cable you are using, and how it works in you circuit? The problem seems to come from faulty wiring, or could just be damaged cables.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an answer... but it might be power consumption problem, ou voltage stability problem. I use a LCD shield with an RFID card reader (contactless card reader like you can find in the subway). When I plug the thing to a 9v battery the contrast is higher than when I connect it to an USB cable.